# XML Parsing error | OSM Script Android

Tags: java, android, debugging, error-handling, openstreetmap

After executing the code below I receive an error stating "Illegal character is query at index 95: overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?debug=way (around:40,54.95092211711581,-7.721371648195827) ["highway"] ["maxspeed"]; ( ._; >; ); out;"

Could anyone have a look at this and offer any advice?

Thanks.

XML File I'm trying to parse:

```
  <way id="64273241">
    <nd ref="768053039"/>
    <nd ref="1922602861"/>
    <nd ref="1922622063"/>
    <nd ref="795319854"/>
    <nd ref="795320324"/>
    <tag k="highway" v="secondary"/>
    <tag k="maxspeed" v="60"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Port Road"/>
    <tag k="oneway" v="no"/>
    <tag k="ref" v="R229"/>
  </way>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

TextView txtLat;
TextView txtLong;
TextView txtSpeed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latTxt);
    txtLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longTxt);
    txtSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carSpeedTxt);

    LocationManager ls = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener li = new mylocationListener();
    ls.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, li);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//Location listener
class mylocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null)
        {
            //Get position
            double lon = location.getLongitude();
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            txtLong.setText("Longitude: " +lon);
            txtLat.setText("Latitude: " + lat);

            //Get speed
            double speed = location.getSpeed();
            txtSpeed.setText(speed + " km/h");

            //Send request to recieve information regarding Speed zones everytime there is a change in location
            //sendRequest(lat+"", lon+"");
            //sendGetRequest(lat+"", lon+"");
            readXML2(lat+"", lon+"");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}

 /**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

public void readXML2(String lat, String lon)
{
    String query = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=way(around:40,"
            +lon+","+lat+")" + " [\"highway\"] [\"maxspeed\"]; ( ._; >; ); out;";


    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        org.w3c.dom.Document document;
        document = documentBuilder.parse(MainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(getXmlFromUrl(query)));

        NodeList nodeNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("way");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeNodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node nNode = nodeNodeList.item(i);

            String limit = nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("maxspeed").getNodeValue();
            TextView curLimitText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.curLimitTxt);
            curLimitText.setText(limit +" km/h");


            System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("maxspeed").getNodeValue());
            System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("lon").getNodeValue());

        }

    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: So what is at line / char 95? Did you setup UTF-8 unicode encoding properly?

Comment: The log just said index 95.. it must be char. No, I haven't set it up. Do I need to?